# Erro na DLL Qt5Widgets.dll quando ela é instalada para outro computador

Tags: c++, qt, deploy, instalador, cmake

Estou tentando exportar uma aplicação construída em Qt 5.7.0 (compilada para 32 bits, apesar do desenvolvimento ocorrer em um ambiente Windows 10, 64 bits) para outro computador (este com Windows 8.1, 32 bits).

Para isso, preparei o script do CMake para fazer a instalação de todas as DLLs dependentes (utilizando o recurso [*BundleUtilities*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/BundleUtilities.html) que existe nas últimas versões do CMake). O script funciona como esperado, copiando o executável e as DLLs para o path configurado como prefixo de instalação.

Porém, ao levar o pacote de arquivos gerado para o computador-alvo e tentar executar a aplicação lá, o seguinte erro ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> [...]\Qt5Widgets.dll não foi projetado para ser executado no Windows
>   ou contém um erro. Tente instalar o programa novamente usando a mídia
>   de instalação original ou contate o administrador do sistema ou o
>   fornecedor do software para obter suporte. Status de erro 0xc000035a.

**Observações:**

1. Deve ser possível perceber que o teste acima foi feito em um Windows 8.1, 32 bits, instalado em uma VMWare (usado apenas para facilitar os testes). Mas eu já fiz o teste também na máquina real e o erro é o mesmo (apesar de que na máquina real o sistema operacional reclama também do Qt5Core.dll, e na VMWare ele reclama apenas do Qt5Widgets.dll).
2. O Qt instalado é o [5.7.0, 32 bits, para Visual Studio 2015](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015-5.7.0.exe). Eu já verifiquei e até mesmo já reinstalei só pra ter certeza de que não estou usando binários de 64 bits por engano.
3. Ao executar na máquina de desenvolvimento, a aplicação funciona normalmente. E essa máquina **não tem** nenhuma outra versão de Qt instalada.
4. Apesar do erro ocorrer em uma DLL do Qt, eu já instalei manualmente na VMWare o [VS 2015 Redistributables](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=48145) (32 bits). Mas o erro persiste.

### MCVE

**Arquivo de código para o executável (`teste.exe`):**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication oApp(argc, argv);

    QLabel oLabel(0, Qt::Dialog);
    oLabel.setWindowFlags(oLabel.windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
    oLabel.setWindowTitle("Teste para o SOPt");
    oLabel.setFixedSize(400, 150);

    oLabel.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    oLabel.setText("Olá Mundo!");
    oLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel { font-size: 50px; color: black; background: white; } QLabel:hover { color: white; background: black; }");

    oLabel.show();
    return oApp.exec();
}
```

Arquivo de configuração do CMake (`CMakeLists.txt`):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(Teste)

#############################################
# Configuração
#############################################

# Tipos de build
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
  set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug" "Release")
endif()

# Configuração do Qt
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

# Arquivos de código
file(GLOB SRC *.cpp *.h)

# Prepara o executável
if(WIN32)
    add_executable(Teste WIN32 ${SRC})
else()
    add_executable(Teste ${SRC})
endif()

# Configura nome do target
set_target_properties(Teste PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME teste)

# Configura libs linkadas
target_link_libraries(Teste Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)

#############################################
# Instalação
#############################################

# Instala o executável
install(TARGETS Teste DESTINATION bin)

# Instala as dependências do Qt
set(APP "\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/teste.exe")
set(DIRS ${QT_LIBRARY_DIRS})
INSTALL(CODE "
   include(BundleUtilities)
   fixup_bundle(\"${APP}\"   \"\"   \"${DIRS}\")
   ")

# Instala outras dependências (VS 2015 Redistributable, etc)
include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
```

Após rodar o CMake, ele irá gerar a solução do Visual Studio. Então, após compilar o projeto "Teste" (que gera o binário) e compilar o projeto "Install" (que copia o binário e as DLLs de dependência para a pasta configurada no prefixo de instalação - variável [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html)), a pasta configurada para instalação contém os seguintes arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> - api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
> - api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
> - api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
> - api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
> - api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
> - api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
> - api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
> - api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
> - api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
> - api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
> - msvcp140.dll
> - Qt5Core.dll
> - Qt5Gui.dll
> - Qt5Widgets.dll
> - teste.exe
> - vcruntime140.dll

Comment: Pergunta boba... As DLLs usadas são as de deploy ou de debug?

Comment: @Bacco A pergunta não é boba não. :) São as de release. O projeto foi compilado e copiado em release (as DLLs do Qt que são de debug têm uma letra "d" no final do nome - por exemplo: Qt5Widgetsd.dll).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nota: A solução final foi dada na edição, adicionada ao final desta
>   resposta.

Eu meio que descobri o que acontece. :/ O erro está na cópia efetuada pelo `BundleUtilities` no script do CMake (não que ele esteja errado, talvez eu é que não soube usar corretamente).

Como o erro reclama que a imagem do binário (no caso, a DLL) é inapropriada, eu usei o utilitário `dumpbin` (instalado juntamente com o Visual Studio no path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\`) e executei:

```
dumpbin Qt5Widgets.dll /headers
```

O resultado indicou que a imagem era, **de fato**, compilada para 64 bits (linha marcada com uma seta):

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file Qt5Widgets.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64) <==========================
               8 number of sections
        56F5814D time date stamp Fri Mar 25 15:19:57 2016
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
            2022 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL
[...]
```

Mas, como eu disse, eu confirmei que a minha instalação do Qt é a de 32 bits. Então eu re-executei o inscript de instalação e prestei atenção à saída do Visual Studio:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  -- Install configuration: "Release"
1>  -- Installing: C:/temp/Data/bin/teste.exe
1>  -- fixup_bundle
1>  --   app='C:/temp/Data/bin/teste.exe'
1>  --   libs=''
1>  --   dirs=''
1>  --   ignoreItems=''
1>  -- fixup_bundle: preparing...
1>  -- fixup_bundle: copying...
1>  -- 1/28: *NOT* copying 'C:/temp/Data/bin/teste.exe'
1>  -- 2/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/Qt5Core.dll'
1>  -- 3/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/Qt5Gui.dll'
1>  -- 4/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/Qt5Widgets.dll'
1>  -- 5/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 6/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 7/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 8/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 9/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 10/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 11/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 12/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 13/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 14/28: copying 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- fixup_bundle: fixing...
1>  -- 15/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/teste.exe'
1>  -- 16/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/Qt5Core.dll'
1>  -- 17/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/Qt5Gui.dll'
1>  -- 18/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/Qt5Widgets.dll'
1>  -- 19/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 20/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 21/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 22/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 23/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 24/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 25/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 26/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 27/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- 28/28: fix-up not required on this platform 'C:/temp/Data/bin/api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll'
1>  -- fixup_bundle: cleaning up...
1>  -- fixup_bundle: verifying...
1>  -- ===========================================================================
1>  -- Analyzing app='C:/temp/Data/bin/teste.exe'
1>  -- bundle='C:/temp/Data/bin'
1>  -- executable='C:/temp/Data/bin/teste.exe'
1>  -- valid='1'
1>  -- executable file 1: C:/temp/Data/bin/teste.exe
1>  -- verified='1'
1>  -- info='Verified 1 executable files in 'C:/temp/Data/bin''
1>  --
1>  -- verified='1'
1>  -- info=''
1>  --
1>  -- fixup_bundle: done
1>  -- Installing: C:/temp/Data/bin/msvcp140.dll
1>  -- Installing: C:/temp/Data/bin/vcruntime140.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Pois é, então tive o desprazer de perceber que o CMake **estava copiando as dependências da origem errada**: ele está copiando de `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex`, que é uma instalação do Miktex (compilador do LaTex para Windows) que eu tenho instalado aqui (e que também usa o Qt para desenvolver suas próprias interfaces gráficas).

> Voltarei a editar esta resposta no futuro. Ainda estou tentando
>   entender o porquê de ele copiar da origem errada. Minha suspeita é que
>   ele procura as dependências na variável de ambiente `PATH` e copia o
>   primeiro que encontrar - apesar [da documentação](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/BundleUtilities.html) não dizer nada a
>   esse respeito (ao menos não claramente).

### EDIÇÃO (Solução Final)

Primeiramente, ocorre que a variável `QT_LIBRARY_DIRS` não existe no Qt5. Aparentemente ela existia no Qt4, mas foi inutilizada na nova versão uma vez que os "targets" (como `Qt5::Core`) fazem desnecessário ter acesso ao diretório de bibliotecas diretamente (ainda assim cada "target" tem o path do seu CMake configurado na variável `<target>_DIR`). Assim, como essa variável não tinha o diretório de onde o `BundleUtilities` deveria pegar as DLLs, ele simplesmente seguia alguma ordem arbitrária.

Eu testei alterando a ordem na variável `PATH`, mas não mudou nada (continuou pegando do Miktex errôneamente). Depois de gastar o dia inteiro estudando o problema, cheguei à conclusão de que o uso de `BundleUtilities` não ajuda muito. A forma como ele encontra as dependências de um executável não é clara (pelo que eu li na documentação ele usa o próprio `dumpbin`, entre outras ferramentas), e mesmo que eu informasse de forma fixa (*hardcoded*) os diretórios de onde ele precisava pegar as dependências, eu descobri depois que ele simplesmente ignorava muitas delas.

Por exemplo, eele não copiou o "plugin" `qwidows.dll`, e mesmo forçando a cópia desse arquivo ele não o copiava para a pasta correta (`./bin/platforms`). Ele também não copiava algumas das DLLs do *C Runtime* (que mudou na versão do Windows 10 e precisa ser distribuído - #bummer).

Assim, eu optei por fazer a cópia dos arquivos manualmente mesmo, **de forma a garantir a origem deles sem problemas**. O script CMake abaixo faz essa cópia sem usar `BundleUtilities`. Sei que o ideal seria identificar automaticamente, mas o diretório de onde buscar as DLLs do C Runtime precisa ser configurado e, por facilidade, eu optei por simplesmente enviar todas elas (mesmo que apenas algumas estejam sendo utilizadas no código).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(Teste)

#############################################
# Configuração
#############################################

# Tipos de build
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
  set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug" "Release")
endif()

# Configuração do Qt
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Core Widgets)

# Arquivos de código
file(GLOB SRC *.cpp *.h)

# Prepara o executável
if(WIN32)
    add_executable(Teste WIN32 ${SRC})
else()
    add_executable(Teste ${SRC})
endif()

# Configura nome do target
set_target_properties(Teste PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME teste)

# Configura libs linkadas
target_link_libraries(Teste Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)

#############################################
# Instalação
#############################################

get_filename_component(QT_BIN_DIR "${Qt5_DIR}/../../../bin" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(QT_PLUGIN_DIR "${Qt5_DIR}/../../../plugins" ABSOLUTE)

# Instala o executável
install(TARGETS Teste DESTINATION bin)

# Instala as dependências do Qt5
install(FILES "${QT_BIN_DIR}/Qt5Core.dll" DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES "${QT_BIN_DIR}/Qt5Gui.dll" DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES "${QT_BIN_DIR}/Qt5Widgets.dll" DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES "${QT_PLUGIN_DIR}/platforms/qwindows.dll" DESTINATION bin/platforms)

# Instala as dependências do Windows 10 CRT
if(WIN32)
    set(WIN10_CRT_REDIST_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Redist/ucrt/DLLs/x86" CACHE STRING "Path of the Windows 10 Universal C Runtime DLLs." FORCE)

    file(GLOB CRTFiles "${WIN10_CRT_REDIST_DIR}/*.dll")
    foreach(CRTFile ${CRTFiles})
      install(FILES ${CRTFile} DESTINATION bin)
    endforeach()
endif()

# Instala demais dependências
include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS} DESTINATION bin)
```